# Best practices: c++ header includes

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm learning C++ at the moment and I think I understand most of what there is to know about including headers... coming from languages where this wasn't necessary at all, I often have the feeling that 'this is wrong' or there should be 'an easier way to do this':

1. I find it very annoying to include (for example) "vector" in every class I want to use a vector. Is there a better way?
2. I've got a good bit of core functionality (also in it's separate namespace) with quite a few classes that doesn't change often. While I don't need all the functionality in every class, it would be very nice to just have one single header file, include that and be done with it... What's the best way to do this?
3. Is it bad practice to include headers in a precompiled header file? If yes, why?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the kind of question SO is for. I suggest googling on the subject, I remember reading a few good tips'n'tricks artices on header management.

Comment: @Dariusz:  I disagree. It is a general question to be sure, but it is well-stated, and not in the form of "Teach me X."  Asking for general advice is OK is the asker can manage to craft a well-asked question that isn't too sweeping or broad.  I think cboe has done that here.

Comment: Note: Douglas Gregor, of the clang team, is working on a module implementation as pioneering work for future standardization. It's late, really late, but we may hope that one day C++ will finally get a proper module system and we can get rid of those headers...

Comment: Sorry if i missused SO, i thought the questions are specific enough!

Comment: As it stands you have 3 questions and they're all very vague.  It is certainly possible to ask the questions that you're trying to ask, but try to reduce it to 1 question at a time, and try to ask for something more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.I find it very annoying to include (for example)  in every class I want to use a vector. Is there a better way?

Imagine how annoying it is for others who use your code (and that other could be **your future self**) and get a compilation error because there is a missing header for `<vector>`. Write it once, use it many times over.

> 2.I've got a good bit of core functionality (also in it's separate namespace) with quite a few classes that doesn't change often. While I
>   don't need all the functionality in every class, it would be very nice
>   to just have one single header file, include that and be done with
>   it... What's the best way to do this?

You can do this for speedup, if you let your IDE include this automatically as a precompiled-header. But for correctness and portability alone you should not rely on it and **always let every header be compilable as a standalone header**. See e.g. Item 23 in [Alexandrescu & Sutter's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) Coding Standard. Build systems like CMake even have macros to test for this.

> 3.Is it bad practice to include headers in a precompiled header file? If yes, why?

You can do it, but it's best to let the IDE do this in order to get better portability. And **those headers better be stable** (the Standard Library or Boost e.g., but never your own project headers).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers, really helped out. I found this to be the most clear one

Answer (score 3):

Your sense that `#include`ing what you need, where you need it is "wrong" likely comes from -- at least in part -- your bias coming from other languages where this isn't necessary.

In C++ the philosophy that drives many paradigms is, "you don't pay for what you don't use or need."  One of the ways this manifests is needing to `#include` whatever headers you need for a component you're writing.  Nothing is `#include`ed automatically.

There are established shortcuts to make this simpler. One such shortcut is the use of so-called pre-compiled headers, or global headers, which themselves `#include` all this low-level stuff that is used globally accross your project.  You would write such a header and `#include` that in any file where it is needed, rather than `#include`ing several (or several dozen) individual files.

One of the benefits of the "you don't pay for what you don't use" philosophy is reaped at compile-time.  If you need only 3 little header files, `#include`ing only those three, rather than dozens of unneeded cruft, will speed up compile times.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not in general but there are exceptions. Even more - you should not rely on includes in included h files, but sometimes you can do this. For instance in derived classes you can pretty much rely on includes of the base.
2. Make your own include which just includes a bunch of other includes. But be careful with that.
3. It is a good practice for huge includes that do not change often. This is also not very common practice on posix systems.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common.h header file. Include all necessary header files in this and include this in all other header files(I don't know about others, but we follow this in my project).

Its a good practice to include pre compiled header file(You have to only include the headers which hardly change). But I have only seen pre compiled header(stdafx.h) in windows c++, not any where else.

Comment: xcode also supports it in .pch file